# jQuery change CSS background of clicked element from many elements with same .class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a simple jQuery script that i want to change the background color of the clicked element.

So here is my code:

```
<dt>
<input id="p_method_banktransfer" value="banktransfer" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Bank Payment"  class="radio validation-passed" autocomplete="off"/>ev
<label for="p_method_banktransfer">Банков превод </label>
</dt>
```

I have many `<dt>...</dt>` tags

Here is the CSS of `<dt>`:

```
.opc-wrapper-opc .payment-block dt { 
background: #3399CC;
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 0px 0px 13px;
position: relative;
}
```

So actually it seems that i am clicking on the label or on the input but the background that i want to change is of that `dt` element.

How i can make it ?

Comment: $(this).parent().css('background', 'red')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', 'dt', function(){
  $(this).css('background','red'); // substitute your color for red
});
```

**UPDATE**

To change all `<dt/>` OTHER than the clicked one back to the original color:

```
$('body').on('click', 'dt', function(){
  $('dt').not(this).css('background', '#3399CC'); // change back to original color
  $(this).css('background','red'); // substitute your color for red
});
```

Comment: Okey it's working but how i can turn the background color to the old one when i click on another `dt` ? I mean i click on element1 and it's going red, then i click on element2 and element1 is going old bg, and element2 is going bg red.